# Check if column is already sorted

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am using the following code to sort the columns in the table using the header row as a trigger.

```
var tr = d3.selectAll("tbody tr");  
d3.selectAll("thead th").data(forsort).on("click", function(k) {  
    tr.sort(function(a,b){  
        return a[k] - b[k]; });  
});
```

The problem is, there are quite a few cells with same values. When I click to sort the table the first time, it does what is expected. But, if i click it again, it will rearrange those rows which have the same valued cell (from the column being used to sort) in them.

I was wondering if there was anyway to check if the column is already sorted and if true then not allow repeated sorting.
Any alternate solutions are also welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
var tr = d3.selectAll("tbody tr");  
lastSort = null;
d3.selectAll("thead th").data(forsort).on("click", function(k) { 
    if(lastSort != k){
        tr.sort(function(a,b){  
            return a[k] - b[k]; 
        });
        lastSort = k;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of how you sorted the table last, and ignore repeated clicks on the same header.

Alternatively you might want to reverse the sorting if the user clicks the header again, that is a fairly common behaviour for a sortable list. Then you would keep track of the last sorted column, and the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your comparator doesn't establish a strict total order. Say you sort by surname, and two rows have the same surname but different name, the sort algorithm can place these two rows in any order, since they're equivalent from the point of view of the compararor. Hence the sorting result is non unique, might be different over multiple executions and unpredictable.

If that's the issue, you should take care of establishing a total order, for instance having a fallback last comparison that might be aebitrary (name, id, timestamp). If really needed, sort based on all the columns, if two rows have all the columns equals, then it doesn't matter in which order they're put.